# How to use .blend file in iphone project?

Tags: iphone, 3d, blender, sio2

I dont want to use any 3D engine like SIO2 etc engines in my project. But I still want to use **.blender 3d files** in my normal projects.

Can anyone please guide me how I can proceed with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .blend format is not much more than a python [pickle object](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) with some binary header fields. It unfortunately is neither very optimized nor easy to load data from.

Also blender format is prone to version differences which are very subtle and will be handled by upgraded blender versions but you will lose a lot of time learning all the differences between the .blend file versions.

I recommend you either roll your own exporter for your own preferred format (should it not exist in the blender community or addons) or use a generic format, some good all-round formats are :

- Collada (Builtin)
- Direct X format (Builtin)

Check for more [blender import and export plugins](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.5/Py/Scripts/Import-Export)

Answer (score 1):

Export your blend file to another format.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.5/Py/Scripts#Import-Export_Scripts

Which you choose depends upon how you will render your objects.  Check out the "raw" exporter, since you are rolling your own renderer.